# C++ Overload function questions?

Tags: c++

if I have 2 functions, these 2 functions should be different, depending on what parameters I put in, right?

```
#include "sub_string.h"


bool is_prefix(const char a[], const char b[]){
  return a[0]==b[0]? true : false;
}

bool is_prefix(const char a[], const char b[], int n){

  if(n==1){
    return is_prefix(a,b);
  }

  return false;

}
```

Comment: What doesn't work as you expect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
bool result = is_prefix(array1, array2);
```

will call the first version.

```
bool result = is_prefix(array1, array2, number);
```

will call the overloaded version.

Which version of `is_prefix()` gets called depends on the arguments used in the call. As long as the two functions differ by parameters numbers and/or types, the compiler know exactly which one to call (but remember that the return type does not count as overloading).